# Can I rotate my display without root permissions?

Tags: permissions, xorg, display-rotation

My office computer is a Dell OptiPlex 7040, with two DisplayPorts and no other video outputs. It's running 12.04LTS. My screen is connected to one DisplayPort, and shows up in xrandr as

```
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080       0.0* 
   1280x1024       0.0  
   1024x768        0.0  
   800x600         0.0  
   640x480         0.0
```

My `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/` contains no settings for the display.

I had seen a few questions here pointing to `nvidia` being a culprit and needing some more configuration, that is not the case here:

The graphics card does not appear to be an `nvidia` one,

```
$ lspci -v
[…]
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 1912 (rev 06) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: Dell Device 06b9
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 7
    Memory at f6000000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16M]
    Memory at e0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=256M]
    I/O ports at f000 [size=64]
    Expansion ROM at <unassigned> [disabled]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
[…]
```

and in any case, drivers for such cards aren't loaded.

```
$ lsmod | grep nv
```

Yet, when trying to rotate the output, I get

```
$ xrandr --output default --rotate left
xrandr: output default cannot use rotation "left" reflection "none"
```

In the “Displays” Setting window, the display is shown as “Laptop” and its main switch and the “Mirror displays” option are disabled and the “Rotation” drop-down menu has only the option “Normal”.

What do I need to do to get my display rotated?

Can I do it without extended permissions? I cannot edit `/etc/` etc., and asking for changes would have to go up and down the bureaucracy and will likely get lost somewhere.